# Different credentials for Routing API and Maps tile API in Here Maps

Tags: here-api

I want to use the API to get a map tile and a routing API with different application codes and application identifiers. So that with the credentials for routing, I could not use the API to get tile maps and vice versa. How can I get these credentials?

Comment: Hi, which version do you use?

Comment: I use 7.2 for routing API.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below **Legacy Modules** in the web pages.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/migration.html

App Id and app code can be uniquely generated for each project. So if you intend to use different app id and code for different apis then you have to create another Project in the project plan page. App ID and Code provides access to all the apis in Here(as per design) and it is up to your code to restrict the usage to particular api. Here only provides domain whitelisting option for any app credentials.

I hope this help.

Comment: But I use REST API.
I want use 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-a-simple-route.html
AND
https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/quick-start-map-tile.html
with differents app code and app id.  So that with the credentials for routing, I could not use the API to get tile maps and vice versa. 
I don't use JAVASCRIPT API